# How to loop trough objects in html

Tags: python, django

I want to loop through my categories in my html. I am making a filter that will show all of the categories but i cant get my {% for %} to work i need some help heres my code. Ask if theres any more info that you need to solve this.

HTML:

```
<div class="filter-box">

<h1>Filter</h1><hr>
{% for category in categorys%}
  <p class="checkbox-text">Hello</p>
  <h1>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
{% endfor %}

</div>
```

Views:

```
def category_all(request):
categorys = Category.objects.all()
return render(request, "product/dashboard_test.html", {"names": categorys})
```

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, it should work for you.

**Code:**

**Python Code:**

```py
def category_all(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'categories': categories
    }
    return render(request, "product/dashboard_test.html", context=context)
```

**HTML Code:**

```html
<div class="filter-box">

<h1>Filter</h1><hr>
{% for category in categories%}
  <p class="checkbox-text">Hello</p>
  <h1>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
{% endfor %}

</div>
```

**Explanations:**

`{"names": categorys}` this implementation is not correct.

Comment: Nope, nothing changed again...

Comment: Do you have data in `Category` table??

Comment: No i dont... why? Do i need it?

Comment: Without data it will not execute for loop in html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are passing in a template variable "names" and then in the template you are trying to call it "categorys"
Change this line:

```
return render(request, "product/dashboard_test.html", {"names": categorys})
```

to this:

```
return render(request, "product/dashboard_test.html", {"categorys": categorys})
```

Also categorys is spelled categories, not that it effects your code

Comment: Nothing changed, its the same

Comment: If "categorys" is empty then the loop has nothing to loop through, hence nothing is printed. In Django you can also add a {% empty %} tag before {% endfor %} and in between these tags you can put the html that should display when there are no categories to display